# Backing up the master boot

Tags: linux, backup, boot, master

I want to back up the master boot on my hard drive, in case something screws it up. What software do you recommend for this?

My first idea is to boot from a Linux CD and dd the first 512 bytes of /dev/sda, and dd it back to recover. Will this solution work, and is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://www.backuphowto.info/backup-mbr-linux

I guess you were right.